# Couldn't install phpmyadmin Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I searched around, couldn't find a solution for this:

```
root@vmi361266:~# sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package phpmyadmin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'phpmyadmin' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the Ubuntu packages, which are maintained to be up-to-date and better than the phpMyAdmin that's included with Debian (and Debian Buster doesn't have the package at all, as you see).

[These](https://launchpad.net/~phpmyadmin/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) should be compatible and updated.

To use them, you probably have to add the PPA as an apt source, which you can do with

`sudo echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/phpmyadmin/ppa/ubuntu eoan main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/phpmyadmin.list`

Try to update apt: `apt-get update`. You'll probably get a key error, which we expect because you don't have the proper key to verify downloads yet. When you get the error, note the key ID.

Retrieve the key: `apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 2EA3055293CB3F45` (at the moment, that is the key that I needed, but that could change, so it's better to copy and paste it from the error message and substitute that in this command).

Finally, you can update the package list again with `apt-get update` then install the `phpmyadmin` package with your favorite apt-flavored tool.